# Have I found correct formula? $\zeta(3)$

Tags: riemann-zeta

Have I found the correct formula? Or is this only numerical aproximation?
$\zeta(3)=\frac{2{\pi}^2}{7}(\ln 2-\frac{4}{15})$

Reedited:
I add another aproximation(may be better):
$\zeta(3)=\frac{2{\pi}^2}{7}(\ln 2-\frac{e\;\pi}{32})$

Just for fun, new one:
$$\zeta(3)\dot{=}4\pi^2\left(\ln\left(\frac{16665385931}{9990000}\right)-e^2\right)$$

Comment: How did you find this formula?

Comment: Your approximation is $\approx 1.2026268$, $\zeta(3) \approx 1.2020569$

Comment: Thank you, as I expected, my guess is only bad aproximation. But may be will inspire real mathematicians to find correct formula.

Answer (score 5):

If such a formula were to exist, AND depend on $\pi$, it would be a function of $\pi^3$. But it's unlikely, since the equation of the circle is NOT $x^3+y^3=r^3$. Which is why [only even zetas depend on $\pi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers).

Comment: Can you expand on your last two sentences please? Where did the comparison to the circle equation come from? I would love to know!

Comment: All even Zetas are dependent upon the value of $\zeta(2)$ due to a combination between Euler's infinite product expression for the sine function, and Euler's formula, as shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2013_April_23#Pi_and_Even_Zeta_Constants). At the same time, there are countless formulas linking the Zeta and Gamma functions. But then again, the Gamma function itself is linked to geometric shapes, as seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2013_May_7#Linking_Factorials_to_Geometric_Shapes).

Answer (score 2):

See [Apéry's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry's_constant). I think that's just an approximation.